# It is possible to change alignments while changing the width of the row in a table?

Tags: tables

I want to Center the content of "Critico", "Alto", "Medio" & "Bajo", but "Total" I want it to right.

```
        \begin{tabular}{m{3.41cm} m{3.41cm} m{3.41cm} m{3.41cm} m{3.41cm}}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{c}{Severidad de los hallazgos} \\
        \hline 
        Critico & Alto & Medio & Bajo & Total \\
        \hline
        2 & 3 & 4 & 29 & 39\\
        \hline
        \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: use `wc{3.41cm}` not `m`